# Google API Hooks, is there a way to be Programmatically Alerted When a Google Doc is Updated?

Tags: cron, notifications, hook

Does Google have an API for registering hooks/callbacks for whenever a document is updated?  That way, I could run a process on one of my servers every time a doc was updated.

If they don't have that, what the recommended way to accomplish that?  Cron?  Anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no mechanism for having Google execute hooks against others' systems.  However, in this case I recommend you use a cron to pull the documents list feed.  To make your life easier, you should probably also use the [updated-min query parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/reference.html#Parameters) with the feed.  This way, you can run a cron every 5 minutes, and give an updated-min date of 6 minutes ago.  The additional minute is to avoid race conditions, so you might see some overlap in what's returned after multiple runs of the cron.

An example:

```
# Assuming it's 10:55:00, you would make a request for 6 minutes ago
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/?updated-min=2010-04-03T10:49:00-08:00
```

For more information, please see the [Documents List Data API Reference Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/reference.html).  Good luck!